# Specify directive controller name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I share a controller between multiple types of directives (kinda like a virtual controller) ?

For example, I would like a tree-like controller :

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c></c>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c></c>
    </b>
</a>
```

Each `a`, `b` and `c` tag should have access to the controller of its closer parent, regardless if it is a `a`, `b` or `c` (but would fail if there wouldn't have such tag in its hierarchy).

Comment: Did you take a look on that part of the `directive` guide that describes how to `require` other controllers?

Comment: @Christoph yes, but I believe that this part talk about requiring a controller, not about the way to share a controller between multiple directives of different names - can be wrong and have misunderstood something, though

Comment: @Christoph is right. `require` is the way to go. You need to define a relationship between two directives so Angular can inject the controller function of one into the other.

Comment: @MichaelBenford what when you have three or more types of directives and you need the controller of the closer one ?

Comment: You can require multiple parent controllers but I'm not sure if Angular tells you witch one is closer. You would probably have to figure that out on your own.

Comment: @MaëlNison You can tell Angular to locate a required controller by searching the element's parent. You just need to use `require: ^directiveName`.